# How can I toggle a <div> before removing it?

Tags: jquery

I want to have this message holder toggle out in a nice way before I remove it from the HTML code, I don't want to add any "setTimeout()" on top on the solution(already have too many at other places in my code).

here is what I have:

```
var messtate;

function slidebubble(number){

$('#messsage'+number).animate({"opacity":1},{queue: false, duration: 1100});
$('#messsage'+number).animate({ "margin-left": "+=260" }, 500);
messtate = setTimeout(function(){ remove(number); }, 6000);
}

function remove(num){
$( "#messsage"+num ).toggle(500).delay(1000).remove();   
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't toggle at all, it only gets removed after 6 seconds, why doesn't the delay work?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use the `hide` function instead of `toggle` in your **remove** method.

With `hide`, you can add a delay, and then a callback to remove the element.

I think it will work.

```
var messtate;

function slidebubble(number){

  $('#messsage'+number).animate({"opacity":1},{queue: false, duration: 1100});
  $('#messsage'+number).animate({ "margin-left": "+=260" }, 500, function() {
    remove(number); 
  });
}

function remove(num){
  $( "#messsage"+num ).hide(6000, function() {
    $(this).remove();   
  });
}
```

Comment: perfect, exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery's animation docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) outline a fourth parameter you can pass to `.animate()` -- `complete`

> A function to call once the animation is complete, called once per matched element.

Since you have two parallel animations, pick the one with the largest duration, and then you can call `remove` from it:

```
function slidebubble (number) {
  $('#message' + number).animate({'margin-left': '+=260'}, 500);
  $('#message' + number).animate({'opacity': 1}, {queue: false, duration: 1100}, null, function () {
    // called when animation is complete
    remove(number);
  });
}

function remove (number) {
  $('#message' + number).toggle(500).delay(1000).remove();

}
```